# @Html.DropDownList return null to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

The `DropDownList` in my view shows the relevant options to choose, but no matter what i choose, the `folders` in the Controller get value `null`.

Why? How can i fix it so the `folders` in the Controller will get the chosen option from the `DropDownList` from the view?

P.S - I have no Model.

This is my Controller:

```
//POST: Home
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Index(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> file, string folder, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> folders)
{
   // some code here
}
```

This is my view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken();

    <div class="container">
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">
                <p></p>
                <label for="file">Upload Photo:</label>
                <input type="file" name="file" id="file" accept="image/*" multiple="multiple"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div>
                    <label>Choose Album:</label>
                    @if (ViewBag.Folders != null)
                    {
                        @Html.DropDownList("folders", new SelectList(ViewBag.Folders as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "Value", "Text"), "--- Select Album ---", new { @class = "form-control" })
                    }

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div>
                    <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: So you want the selected folder, correct?  Why is the Action also expecting **folders**?

Comment: actually... why is it expecting folder __AND__ folders?

Comment: `folder` is for creating new folder (which is working fine), `folders` is to choose a folder from the existing folders. any way, the names not relevant, they can all A and B... B is the data from the `DropDownList` and i get `null` instead value, that is the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Sakthivel Ganesan, after changing the `IEnumerable<SelectListItem> folders` in the Controller to `string folders`, the only thing left to do is to change my `Html.DropDownList` `Value` to `Text` like this...

from :

```
@Html.DropDownList("folders", new SelectList(ViewBag.Folders, "Value", "Text"), "--- Select Album ---", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

To:

```
@Html.DropDownList("folders", new SelectList(ViewBag.Folders, "Text", "Text"), "--- Select Album ---", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Answer (score 0):

in order to get the folder, give your dropdownlist the corresponding name ...

@Html.DropDownList("folders"...

will result in your DDL to have the name "folders" ... which will try to post back a single item... `folders` in your method is a `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` ... the modelbinder is incapable to convert that ...

try

@Html.DropDownList("folder"...

note the missing s

now the name corresponds to the `string folder` parameter in your method... which the binder will most likely be able to bind for you...

if you debug errors like this, use the debugger to have a look at `HttpContext.Request.Params`, which will show you what was coming back when the request was made...

Comment: So i need to change the `flders` type in the controller from `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` to `string`?

Answer (score 0):

Parameter type should be changed from IEnumerable to String as view returns only selected item NOT collection.

```
//POST: Home
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Index(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> file, string folder, string folders)
{
   // some code here
}
```

Comment: I changed it to `string` as you suggested, not instead of `null` i get empty value like " "... still have a problem

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to give another option.  If you're able to leverage a client-side solution, then you could muscle this a bit with a hidden input value and JQuery.

Add a hidden input control:

```
<input name="selectedFolder" type="hidden" value="" />
```

Add some Jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$("#folders").on("change", function {
   $("#selectedFolder").val($(this).text());
 });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I less understand JQuery, but... if i add your suggestion to my code, will it work? the selected item from my `DropDownList` will go trough to the Controller?